# Print size and count in adjacent rather than in new line in Perl

Tags: perl, formatting, report

I have written a script which will fetch values from db and store it in the hash called  `total_hash`. To make question simpler I have hard coded the hash here.

Next step I need to display these hash content in table format, so used a below logic to display it on the screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $method_total = 1;
my $method_a = 1;
my $method_b = 1;
my $method_sync = 1;

my %total_hash = (
  'Method_Combine' => {
              'flag' => 1,
              'count' => 27,
              'name' => '| Method TOTAL',
              'size' => 270
            },
  'Method_A' => {
                'count' => 7,
                'flag' => 1,
                'name' => '| Method A',
                'size' => 70
              },
  'Method_B' => {
                'count' => 20,
                'flag' => 1,
                'size' => 200,
                'name' => '| Method B'
              },
  'Method_Sync' => {
               'name' => '| Method Sync',
               'size' => 300,
               'flag' => 1,
               'count' => 30
             }
);
#print "total_hash:\n".Dumper(\%total_hash);

printReport(\%total_hash);

sub printReport {
    my $hash = shift;
    my $string1 = "";
    my $string2 = "";
    my $string3 = "";
    my $append_data = "";
    my $length = 20;
    my $total_length = $length * ($method_sync + $method_a + $method_b + $method_total) + 1;
    my @columns = ('Method_Sync','Method_A','Method_B','Method_Combine');

    foreach my $key (@columns) {
        if ($hash->{$key}->{flag}) {
            $append_data = sprintf("%-".$length."s",$hash->{$key}->{name});
            $string1 .= $append_data;
            $append_data = sprintf("%-".$length."s","| ".$hash->{$key}->{size}." Bytes");
            $string2 .= $append_data;
            $append_data = sprintf("%-".$length."s","| ".$hash->{$key}->{count});
            $string3 .= $append_data;
        }
    }
    print("Report:\n\n");
    print "-" x $total_length."\n";
    print $string1 . "|\n";
    print "-" x $total_length."\n";
    print $string2 . "|\n";
    print "-" x $total_length."\n";
    print $string3 . "|\n";
    print "-" x $total_length."\n";
}
```

Here content is getting printing like below (actual ouput):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Method Sync       | Method A          | Method B          | Method TOTAL      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 300 Bytes         | 70 Bytes          | 200 Bytes         | 270 Bytes         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 30                | 7                 | 20                | 10                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want it to be printed like below (expected result):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Method Sync       | Method Sync Count | Method A          | Method A Count    | Method B          | Method B Count    | Method TOTAL      | Method TOTAL Count|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 300 Bytes         | 30                | 70 Bytes          | 7                 | 200 Bytes         | 20                | 270 Bytes         | 27                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each of the Methods Size and Count should be printed adjacent side rather than printing in the new line for the count. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to format it for display as desired.

To align the key names with their size/count prepare columns with name, value(s), and width (maximum between the name and the corresponding value). Then lay them out: first the line with headers then line(s) with their corresponding data, all using their column's width. Add separators per taste (see comment on that at the end)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
#use Data::Dump qw(dd);
use List::Util qw(max);

my %total_hash = (
    'Method_Combine' => 
        { 'count' => 27, 'name' => 'Method TOTAL', 'size' => 270 },
    'Method_A' =>       
        { 'count' => 7,  'name' => 'Method A',     'size' => 70 },
    'Method_B' =>       
        { 'count' => 20, 'name' => 'Method B',     'size' => 200 },
    'Method_Sync' =>    
        { 'count' => 30, 'name' => 'Method Sync',  'size' => 300 }
);

my @keys = qw(Method_Sync Method_A Method_B Method_Combine);  # ordered

my @cols;
for (@keys) { 
    push @cols, { 
        header => $total_hash{$_}{name}, 
        data   => $total_hash{$_}{size} . ' Bytes',
        width  => max map { length } 
            ($total_hash{$_}{name}, $total_hash{$_}{size} . ' Bytes')
    };
    push @cols, { 
        header => $total_hash{$_}{name} . ' ' . 'Count',
        data   => $total_hash{$_}{count},
        width  => max map { length } 
            ($total_hash{$_}{name} . ' ' . 'Count', $total_hash{$_}{count})
    };
}
# dd \@cols;  # just to see it

my $hdr_str = '| ' . join(' | ', 
    map { sprintf "%-*s", $_->{width}, $_->{header} } @cols) . ' |';
my $dat_str = '| ' . join(' | ', 
    map { sprintf "%-*s", $_->{width}, $_->{data} }  @cols) . ' |';
my $sep = '-' x length $hdr_str;

say for $sep, $hdr_str, $sep, $dat_str, $sep;
```

Prints

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Method Sync | Method Sync Count | Method A | Method A Count |  Method B | Method B Count | Method TOTAL | Method TOTAL Count |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 300 Bytes   | 30                | 70 Bytes | 7              | 200 Bytes | 20             | 270 Bytes    | 27                 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've changed the hash and requirements a little

- I formatted columns to be each as wide as needed, not all the same.  That only takes *more* work and if you want them all to be the same width it's easier: find the maximum width of all names and values and use that everywhere. No need for `width` element then
- I've removed the purely formatting part (`|` ) of the string which is the value of `name`.  While I can see the rationale for having it there, it is generally better to separate data from format; those bars are easily added as needed (or not, or something else can be)
- I've also removed a key/value which is unused here (`flag => 1`), for easier viewing

There are of course libraries for this, once we've prepared header and data columns, like text-templates and various modules for formatted/tabular print of text.<sup>†</sup> Then there is also Perl's own [format](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform), and better yet [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form). But [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf) is adequate here.

A note on style.  Experience shows that extra formatting elements in tables generally end up distracting rather than helping. It is usually enough to separate a header, and have sufficient spacing between columns. Other than that, less is more for clarity.  Perhaps consider

```
 Method Sync    Method Sync Count    Method A    Method A Count   
----------------------------------------------------------------    ...
 300 Bytes      30                   70 Bytes    7
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Some libraries: [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table), [Text::TabularDisplay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::TabularDisplay), [Text::SimpleTable::Autowidth](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::SimpleTable::AutoWidth)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I included the `flag` which is needed for me in some cases. Also `width` element I've made constant, for better viewing.

Comment: I tried with `format`, but ended up with some problem, so I thought of going with above option. Anyway this answer is much helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @vkk05 Yeah, it looked like you've done some thoughtful work on this; I added comments / opinion merely for your consideration :).  I find that `format` can be picky to get just the way you want...  Glad that this helps. let me know if questions come up

Comment: @vkk05 Added a list of libraries